# Approximation to photoshop's s-curve filter?

Tags: image-processing

What is the fastest approximation (formula) to the s-curve color filter in photoshop? I need the simplest possible form to be able to use it in a shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to combine two functions: [image: img], and its inverse graph [image: img]. The issue lies in combining the functions at x=0.5. First function gives 0.25, and the other one gives 0.75.

After some experimentation it seems that the following approximation is good enough:

[image: img]

[image: img]

[image: graph]